# Github Workflows - Add manual step in the middle of the workflow

Tags: github-actions

This is how my Worfklow looks like right now:

It runs unit and integration tests in parallel, and if both passes, the Staging and Production deploy run.

I'm wondering if there's a way to add a manual step only to the deploy step. I don't want to deploy to Staging every single time.

Is there any way of achieving it?

test.yml

```
name: Test, Build

on:
  workflow_call:

jobs:
  all-tests:
    name: All Tests
    runs-on: [self-hosted]
    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres:11.5-alpine
        env:
          POSTGRES_USER: ''
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ''
          POSTGRES_DB: ''
        ports:
          - 5445:5432
        options: --health-cmd pg_isready --health-interval 10s --health-timeout 5s --health-retries 5
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Run migrations
        env:
          ENVIRONMENT: 'test'
          DATABASE_URL: ''
        run: ./gradlew flywayMigrate
      - name: Integration Test
        env:
          ENVIRONMENT: 'test'
        run: ./gradlew test
```

deploy.yml

```
name: Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  test:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/test.yml
  deploy-staging:
    name: Deploy Staging
    runs-on: [self-hosted]
    needs: [test]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Migrations
        env:
          ENVIRONMENT: 'staging'
          DATABASE_URL: ${{ secrets.DATABASE_URL_STAGING_MIGRATION }}
        run: ./gradlew flywayMigrate
      - name: Authenticate
        with:
          credentials_json: '${{ secrets.GCP_SA_KEY_STAGING }}'
        uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v0'
      - name: Print Config Files
        env:
          ENVIRONMENT: 'staging'
        run: ./gradlew appengineShowConfiguration
      - name: Stage Deploy
        env:
          ENVIRONMENT: 'staging'
          DATABASE_URL: ${{ secrets.DATABASE_URL_STAGING }}
        run: ./gradlew appengineDeploy
  deploy-prod:
    name: Deploy Prod
    runs-on: [self-hosted]
    needs: [test]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Migrations
        env:
          ENVIRONMENT: 'production'
          DATABASE_URL: ${{ secrets.DATABASE_URL_MIGRATION }}
        run: ./gradlew flywayMigrate
      - name: Authenticate
        with:
          credentials_json: '${{ secrets.GCP_SA_KEY }}'
        uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v0'
      - name: Print Config Files
        env:
          ENVIRONMENT: 'production'
        run: ./gradlew appengineShowConfiguration
      - name: Deploy
        env:
          ENVIRONMENT: 'production'
          DATABASE_URL: ${{ secrets.DATABASE_URL }}
        run: ./gradlew appengineDeploy
```

[image: Github workflow with test and deploy steps]

Answer (score 1):

For manual deploys you need [workflow dispatch](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch) event.

```
on: workflow_dispatch

jobs:
  deploy-staging:
    name: Deploy Staging
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Deploy
        run: <your_staging_deploy_command>
```

Then you need to [manually run a workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/manually-running-a-workflow#running-a-workflow) using Github interface.

Comment: thank you. it's not exactly what i'm looking for, since I would need to do a new commit in case I realize that I want to deploy to staging, which would result in the entire pipeline running again

Comment: I updated my answer to provide information about an isolated workflow separated from any other step on the workflow you provided.

Comment: Thank you Roberto. I have tried it before but the issue is that, as you can see on the image I provided, the Deploy Staging can only be triggered after the tests, through the "needs: [test]". And workflow_dispatch does not work if I have a job that depends on another job.

Comment: @bpereira: It should work if your test job triggers the deploy (staging) job after its completion. `needs` will be redundant in this case and there will only be `workflow_dispatch` event configured for the deploy job. Please include your relevant workflows in your question to highlight other restrictions if there are any.

Comment: @Azeem I have added my .yml to the question

Comment: @bpereira: Thanks! Now, given your deploy workflow, you can replace `push` with `workflow_dispatch` and at the end of your test workflow, you can trigger deploy workflow e.g. via GitHub CLI or REST API. See `[gh workflow run`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_workflow_run) command (its docs [link](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/manually-running-a-workflow#running-a-workflow) is already attached in this answer).